# Variable does not increment in probability program

Tags: java, for-loop, increment, probability

I have three classes. A super class `probability`, a subclass `Eating` and a runner class `Person`.

The goal is for certain methods to be "triggered" when conditions are met in a for loop. Eating (method dox) will increase the variable weight. Once weight is greater than 120, then the probability (int `px`) of dox being called decreases and the probability (`py`) of exercising increases until weight drops below a threshold.

However my int `px` NEVER decreases. Why is this? Below are my decrease probability methods and the trigger that calls them.

```
public void Trigger()
{
    if (weight >= 120)
    {
        dProb(px);
        dProb(pz);
        iProb(py);
    }
    if (weight <= 80)
    {
        dProb(py);
        iProb(px);
        iProb(pz);
    }


public void dProb(int p)
{
    p -= 5;
} 
public void iProb (int p)
{
    p += 5;
}
```

Comment: Java is pass-by-value (google what that means) so this will never work. Why do you need a method for `py += 5` anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is a *local* variable for the method `dProb`, and it's a different variable than `p` in `iProb`. Meaning that `px`, `pz` and `py` are not affected (Java passes *by value*, always).

When you enter the method, a temporary variable is created, and will be destroyed as soon as you exit it.

You should make `p` a *class member* (read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)), or let the methods return the result, and assign it to the caller, or directly modify `px`, `py` and `pz`.